# outputtable based on a data frame from an observe event

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to make a shiny app that shows the table filtered by the user selection.

here is the procedure , i thought would work:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(

    radioButtons('option','class',choices = c('suv','compact') ),

    tableOutput('table')

  )

)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

observeEvent(input$w, {

 ifelse(input$option =='compact',

         sp.1. <- subset(mpg, class='compact'),

          ifelse(input$option =='suv',

            sp.1 <- subset(mpg, class='compact'),

              sp.1 <- mpg)

         )

  })

  output$table <- renderTable({(sp.1)}) 
  })

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

but this does not seem to work, any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I might suggest checking out these videos for a good intro to Shiny: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/. You seem to have quite a few fundamental problems here. A good basic intro might help sort those out. I'm not sure where `input$w` is supposed to be coming from and you need to work with reactive objects for output to update (not standard R variables).

Comment: you are right, i am not learning properly, i am learning by doing a real time project, and its a lot to absorb, but i am really into it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`observeEvent()` does not return any objects and acts as an isolated environment, this is why you are not getting sp.1. Think of `observeEvent` as a function that doesn't allow for a return argument. In order to counter this simply place the `output$table` in the `observeEvent` environment so it can access sp.1.

Note I do not know what `input$w` is, but I tested with a action button labeled "w" to trigger the observeEvent.

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$w, {

     ifelse(input$option =='compact',

       sp.1. <- subset(mpg, class='compact'),

       ifelse(input$option =='suv',

              sp.1 <- subset(mpg, class='compact'),

              sp.1 <- mpg)

    )

    output$table <- renderTable({(sp.1)}) 
  })

  })



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

`observeEvent` in itself is a reactive environment, in that it updates values based on a trigger (the event). Other reactive environments, like `reactive`, do not require a defined event and instead work to look for any change to the variables, and these reactive variables are called as a function. `observe` and `eventReactivw` are other reactive environments and work a lot like `observeEvent` except the variables can be returned to the main environment.

Comment: @Fahadakbar No problem